# Generating a list of combinations based on criteria from a second column of data

Tags: r, combinations, multiple-columns, permutation

I have a simple data frame that includes two columns: Participant ID's (character variable) and Participant scores. I need to generate all possible sets of five participants, however the sum of their scores cannot exceed 15. I understand how to use gtools' combination and permutation functions to make combinations of five Participant IDs (without repeating the same ID within a group), but I am stuck with how to keep those IDs connected with their scores so that I can calculate the score sums for each combination and then filter to the ones that meet the criteria. Any ideas?
I need the outputs to look something like this:
Group 1: A, B, C, I, K (score sum = 14.5)
Group 2: A, C, I, L, M (score sum = 14)
...

```
id <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M")
score <- c(4.5, 5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4, 3.5, 5, 2, 1, 0, 1.5, 3)
dat1 <- data.frame(id, score)

# permutations 
library(gtools)
N <- length(dat1$id) #size of sampling vector
n <- 5 #size of samples

x = permutations(n=N, r=n, v=id, repeats.allowed=F)
# n = size of sampling vector 
# r = size of samples 
# v = vector to sample from
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to convert it to a data frame, and then use {tidyr} to pivot the data, join it to your data frame of values, group by the permutation, add up the scores, and then pivot it back:

```
colnames(x) = 1:5
x |> 
  as_tibble() |> 
  mutate(id = row_number()) |> 
  pivot_longer(-id) |> 
  left_join(dat1, by = c("value" = "id")) |> 
  group_by(id) |> 
  mutate(score = sum(score)) |> 
  filter(score <= 15) |> 
  pivot_wider(values_from = value, names_from = name)
```

returns

```
# A tibble: 73,440 × 7
# Groups:   id [73,440]
      id score `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`  
   <int> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1    52  14.5 A     B     C     I     K    
 2    61  13.5 A     B     C     J     K    
 3    62  15   A     B     C     J     L    
 4    69  14.5 A     B     C     K     I    
 5    70  13.5 A     B     C     K     J
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `combn()` to get the unique grps, and then use `apply()` by row to get the group scores, leverage a named version of `scores`.

```
# name the elements of the scores vector
names(scores) <- id

# generate a data frame with the unique combinations
grp_scores <- data.frame(t(combn(id,5)))

# assign the scores by summing the elements of the
grp_scores['score'] <- apply(grp_scores, 1, \(x) sum(score[x]))

# reduce to the rows where the sum is less than or equal to 15
grp_scores <- grp_scores[grp_scores$score<=15,]
```